# xsl decoding my xml

Tags: xml

i dont want the xslt to decode xml like chngeing html sequence and other things is there any thing i can add to the template to seect it words as it is like

```
select="node() some code"
```

thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the [disable-output-escaping](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#disable-output-escaping) option:

```
<xsl:value-of select="node()" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```